# How close to the moon would a flyby trip likely attempt?

Tags: the-moon, flyby

For a flyby of the moon, like the SpaceX #dearMoon flight announced September 17, 2018, how close would they likely attempt to pass?

Is there an average or optimal trajectory for a lunar flyby used on past missions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SpaceX has posted a nice info graphic:

[image]

The perilune (closest approach to the moon, number 06 in the graphic) is going to be [about 125 miles / 201 km](https://www.forbes.com/sites/alexknapp/2018/09/17/billionaire-yusaku-maezawa-has-bought-the-first-spacex-trip-around-the-moon-in-2023and-hes-bringing-artists-with-him/#12a11b458155).

Comment: During the Q/A after the presentation where this was shown, musk mentioned that the flight plan wasn't final and he could imagine doing a close flyby and then a long return.

Answer (score 0):

On May 17, 2018 NASA's TESS passed within 8,253.54 km of the lunar surface on a flyby. This is roughly equivelant to 2% of the distance between Earth and the Moon.

(Source: https://mobile.twitter.com/nasa_tess/status/997485558283882501?s=21)

Comment: distance of closest approach would depend on the exact nature of the maneuver. Wouldn't an Apollo-ere free return at least be a better starting point than TESS? https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21544/12102 and also https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21096/12102 The delta-v that TESS needed was much less than what's required for a lunar u-turn.  https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26577/12102 (and also https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27319/12102)

Comment: Absolutely. And hopefully it is significantly closer than that!